# Linq to XML query involving attributes

Tags: xml, linq

I have the following xml

```
<root>
<document>
    <account>12</account>
    <type name-"a">stuff</type>
    <type name-"b">stuff</type>
</document>
<document>
    <account>42</account>
    <type name-"a">stuff</type>
    <type name-"b">good stuff</type>
    <type name-"c">good stuff</type>
</document>
</root>
```

I want to return using LINQ to XML a Document class object for each document in the xml for
the account value and type value where the type attribute name is "b" into the class

```
class Document {
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string BType { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure how I iterate over the types or whether you can be neater than that with a predicate

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("document")
             .Where(x => x.Elements("type")
                          .Any(b => (string) b.Attribute("name") == "b"))
             .Select(x => new Document {
                        Account = (string) x.Element("account")
                        BType = x.Elements("type")
                                 .First(b => (string) b.Attribute("name") == "b")
                                 .Value
                     });
```

Alternatively:

```
var query = from d in doc.Descendants("document")
            let b = d.Elements("type")
                     .FirstOrDefault((string) d.Attribute("name") == "b")
            where b != null
            select new Document { Account = (string) d.Element("account"),
                                  BType = b.Value };
```